# What do the ending scenes of Lucy in relation to the universe mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, lucy

I understand in the end, Lucy uses 100% brain (rather than the usual 10%) and becomes Omnipotent. 
(Though I am aware that the director used [the 10% myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_percent_of_the_brain_myth) rather than the actual logic for the brain.)

But my doubt is about the minutes after the earth burns and splits into two planets. This shot below really confused me.

[image]

Can anyone explain whats that they show in these last sequences?

Comment: The origin of the universe.

Comment: More idiotic mumbo-jumbo that makes no sense in any context or suspension of belief.  You can tell, I'm not a fan...

Answer (score 8):

The sequence you are referring to ("the earth splitting into two planets"), is actually **a huge asteroid hitting earth**, because the whole sequence is reversed.**Lucy is going further back in time**, observing **how the earth was formed**, and before that, **how the galaxies were scattered across the universe** and ultimately culminating (backwards) to **the origin of the universe**, the Big Bang, the explosion of a singularity or single point which contained all the energy in the universe (not sure about the physics here). She performed all of this with **99%** of her brain's power. Once she reaches the big bang the screen shows **100%**.

Then, the shot goes back to the room Lucy was in with the scientists, but her **physical body disappears** right before Jang fires his weapon. Then Jang gets shot, and the "moving computer" (Lucy?) produces a **pen drive with a space-like (starry) texture**, which I think represents all the **knowledge Lucy gathered** in that sequence, and which she made available to mankind.

Finally, Del Rio asks the scientists: **"Where is she"**, and Lucy displays the answer on the man's own cell phone:**"I am everywhere"**, which indicates **she became an omnipotent, god-like being**.

I believe, based on this last scene, that the director's opinion is that no human will ever reach 100% usage of his/her brain, because **that would mean becoming a god**. Is god a being that can use the full potential of their intellect? Interesting ending for this movie.

Comment: wow, cool. Thanks for that explanation!
so the pic i put up was the big bang? shud they be gaseous clouds flying out from the center?

Comment: No, I believe that may be the formation of the moon (which is thought to have formed from an asteroid hitting earth. See http://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/08/science/moon-formation.html?module=WatchingPortal&region=c-column-middle-span-region&pgType=Homepage&action=click&mediaId=thumb_square&state=standard&contentPlacement=53&version=internal&contentCollection=www.nytimes.com&contentId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2016%2F11%2F08%2Fscience%2Fmoon-formation.html&eventName=Watching-article-click

Comment: @VishnuKumar 
To be quite honest, I don't know which moment of the universe's formation would best fit your picture. They kind of look like spermatozoids though. There is also a scene where it looks like cell replication, only reversed.

Comment: @AjayKumarRaja
Interesting, I did not know that was the most accepted theory regarding the moon's formation. Still, what I said in the answer wasn't wrong, just incomplete due to my lack of knowledge in Astronomy. Also, that scene is so fast it is hard to catch many details of it. Btw, thanks for improving my answer, you put the proper names I had forgotten.

Comment: @AjayKumarRaja, am aware of the moon/earth creation, my question was about the scenes after that.

Comment: @DukeZhou, thats why i have the wikipedia link in my question.

Comment: @MatheusRotta, lol i agree on the spermatozoids thing, that was my initial reaction. A second later, i began to see it as E.T. beings. But it was neither cos when the camera rotates on those, it shows up as gaseous stuff... Thats why i wanted to know what it was...

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen Lucy so I assumed that this was that scene.